# Submenu is not showing active when I select any page of that options

Tags: jquery, submenu, jquery-ui-accordion, side-menu

I am using jQuery accordion, inside it having a main menu and its options, Inside it having sub-menu and its options.

When I click any option of main menu and page renders then menu shows active and OPEN, but when I click and open any page from sub-menu, page renders but after that sub-menu is closed automatically. It should be shown open as parent menu remains open after page renders.

HTML

```
<div id="main">
     <div class="sidebar-collapse">
    <ul id="navigation" class="nav side-menu">
       <li>
        <s:a action='home' class="head1">Dashboard</s:a>
       </li>

       <li>
        <a style="cursor: pointer" class="head">
           <i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            Reports Section
        </a>

     <ul>
       <li><s:a action='abc1'>Report 1</s:a></li>
       <li><s:a action='abc2'>Report 2</s:a></li>       
       <li><s:a action='abc3'>Report 3</s:a></li>

        <ul id="sub-accordian">
           <li class="active">
              <a class="head2">
               Sub-Menu Reports
               </a>

        <ul>
           <li><s:a action='xyz1'>Sub-Report 1</s:a></li>
           <li><s:a action='xyz2'>Sub-Report 2</s:a></li>
           <li><s:a action='xyz3'>Sub-Report 3</s:a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
          </ul>                             
    </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery().ready(
            function() {
                jQuery('#navigation').accordion({
                    active : true,
                    header : '.head',
                    navigation : true,
                    event : 'click',
                    fillSpace : false,
                    animated : 'easeslide',
                    collapsible: true
                });

                jQuery('#sub-accordian').accordion({
                    active : true,
                    header : '.head2',
                    navigation : true,
                    event : 'click',
                    fillSpace : false,
                    animated : 'easeslide',
                    collapsible: true
                });
            });
</script>
```

I wants that when I open any page from sub-menu after clicking then sub-menu should be open and active, it should not close automatically.

Comment: you need to save the state in storage, the site doesn't know what tab to open after the refresh

Comment: But how this can be achieved when we select any option from main menu, after page renders and main menu still shows open and active but in sub-menu why we need to save state in storage then ?